# Drag And Drop in the Same Container

Tags: javascript, html

I have referred following code to drag and drop in the same container; 
drag_over and drop function can not be called; please provide some alternative
Note: Using Chrome and FireFox browser.

```
        function drag_start(event) {
            var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null);
            event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain",
                    (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"), 10) - event.clientX) + ',' + (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top"), 10) - event.clientY));
        }
        function drag_over(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        function drop(event) {
            var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');
            var dm = document.getElementById('drag_div');
            dm.style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0], 10)) + 'px';
            dm.style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1], 10)) + 'px';

            event.preventDefault();
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var dm = document.getElementById('drag_div');
            dm.addEventListener('dragstart', drag_start, false);

            document.body.addEventListener('dragover', drag_over, false);
            document.body.addEventListener('drop', drop, false);

        });
```

Comment: "please provide some alternative", so you failed out of search ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo :

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>

<p id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69"> Drag me to the box </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how to get drop item attribute id?

Comment: Can you elaborate. I didn't get your question.

Comment: according to the code, id="drag1" is dragged and dropped into the id="div1"; suppose if there is more than one item for drag; then on dropping how can I get dropped item id?

Comment: Try this. I've added one more drag item and included into drop box. For further enhancement create drag tags as per requirements  and expand the size of drop box as per requirements.

Code :: Follow this link for further understandings. 

"https://textuploader.com/dz79i"